# WSO2 ESB - start multiple instance of ESB with different port(receiving/listening port) from single installation of WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Is it possible to start multiple instance of WSO2 ESB with different port configuration for each instance but from single installation of WSO2 ESB?

Like we do with tomcat (CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE).

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK OOTB you can't start multiple instances of WSO2 ESB (or any Carbon based products) from a single installation as now.

But you can simply have multiple server installations (just unzip to **wso2esb-x.x.x.zip** to multiple folders). And run the server with -DportOffset option as follows,

```
$sh <CARBON_HOME>/bin/wso2server.sh -DportOffset=1
```

(Or use bat file if you are in windows)

Or if you want persist the port offset, you can open `<CARBON_HOME>/repository/conf/carbon.xml` file then search for tag `<Offset>` and set a port offset as follows,

```
<Offset>1</Offset>
```

And run the server with as usual (without the port offset option),

```
$sh <CARBON_HOME>/bin/wso2server.sh
```

HTH,

DarRay

Comment: Thanks DarRay, Already I have this solution as back-up but I look for is there a way to start multiple instance from single installation of WSO2 ESB.

Comment: @BalajiSengeni Since creating another installation is very simple, its not been a barrier not having above functionality. And in production environments its normally having separate VMs for each instances.