# Regarding port issue in WSO2 ESB https://localhost:9443/carbon is there any possibility to change default port no of wso2esb to another port number

Tags: port, wso2, wso2-esb

I am new to WSO2 ESB I am facing problem with port number...9443 port number is already listening to another service. I am unable stop that service is there any possibility to change port in WSO2 ESB to another port no,
i. e. `https://localhost:9443/carbon` to `https://localhost:<some other port number>/carbon`?

Answer (score 1):

In the /repository/conf/carbon.xml file, you can also specify the port offset value. This is ONLY applicable if you have multiple WSO2 products hosted on the same server.

```
<Ports>
  ...
  <Offset>0</Offset>
  ...
</Ports>
```

Click [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+ESB+4.9.0) for more information on configuring the port offset.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a port offset and change the default port. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144774/wso2-esb-start-multiple-instance-of-esb-with-different-portreceiving-listenin).